# IOEXCEP The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process using Streamwriter

Tags: c#

When I run this it gives me the error in the title
I've tried adding `writer.Close();` everywhere and I still doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Media;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.IO.File;

namespace Soundboard_Maker
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> sounds = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public static StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            writer.Close(); //ERROR
            Commands.AddSound();
            Commands.ScanFile();
            Console.WriteLine(sounds);
        }

        public static string path = @"C:\Users\ecsti\source\repos\Soundboard Maker\Sounds\TextFile1.txt";
        public static int numOfLines = ReadAllLines(path).Length;
        public static void AddSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insert the path of the wav file");
            string soundpath = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Insert the name to use to play the command");
            string soundname = Console.ReadLine();
            writer.WriteLine(soundname + "" + soundpath);
            writer.Close();
            ScanFile();
        }

        public static void ScanFile()
        {
            string[] lines = new string[numOfLines];
            lines = ReadAllLines(path);
            string[] vs = new string[1];
            if (sounds.Count > 0)
            {
                sounds.Clear();
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < lines.Length; j++)
            {
                vs = lines[j].Split(" ");
                sounds.Add(vs[0], vs[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Issue may be you need to use 'using' for your streamwriter.

Comment: Too much global variables. Half of them are totally not needed

Comment: A tip, as a general rule, when it comes to reading writing files, you should try to 'get in and get out' in as small a scope as possible. In other words, try to instantiate, use, and close your reader/writers within the scope of a method and not a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of StreamWriter to the method:

```
public static void AddSound()
{
     Console.WriteLine("Insert the path of the wav file");
     string soundpath = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine("Insert the name to use to play the command");
     string soundname = Console.ReadLine();
     using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, true)) 
     {
         writer.WriteLine(soundname + "" + soundpath);
     }
     ScanFile();
}
```

Somehow the file is not being released. It's better to do it within a using block because it will release the resource regardless of an exception happening.